# JavaScript click is taking time while loading appending a template in Android Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

I have three tabs and onClick of them i m making that tab active and displaying the corresponding data using appending a template to html.
This is working fine if I am not appending the data into html but while appending the html,click is not making the selected tab active until the html is appended.
I want to reflect the click event immediately.

my code is like this:

```
$("#sent, #all, #received").bind("click", function() {
    $("#sent, #all, #received").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');     
    DashBoardManager.updateCommunications();    
});


DashBoardManager.updateCommunications= new function(){
       $("#communicationMainId").html('');
       $.tmpl('communicationTmpl',DashBoradManager.allCommunications)
                .appendTo("#communicationMainId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are appending the data on the UI(main) thread. Consider separating the main thread from your data handling thread, allowing the main thread to load and display your new tab *alongside* a second thread appending the data, rather than during/after.

Edit: [Here is Google's take on the matter:](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

> When your app performs intensive work in response to user interaction,
>   this single thread model can yield poor performance unless you
>   implement your application properly. Specifically, if everything is
>   happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network
>   access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is
>   blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From
>   the user's perspective, the application appears to hang

Comment: Would you give me an example in javascript for this, not in java please.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not adept enough in Javascript to provide you with an example. I imagine that you can find a tutorial for this somewhere, now you know what to search for. Apologies i cannot help further.